# Неправильные операции с числом

Tags: php

Неправильно делится число на число. В данном случае **`$amount = 0.2`** и мы **делим его на 0.2**. Но почему-то выдаётся ответ 0, хотя **должен быть 1**. В чём проблема?

`intval` и `int` у `$xml->operation->amount;` не помог.

```
  $ch = curl_init('https://merchant.webmoney.ru/conf/xml/XMLTransGet.asp');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request_wm);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);

  // разбираем ответ
  $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($result);
  $retval = $xml->retval;
  $amount = $xml->operation->amount;
  $points = $amount/0.2;

  echo $points;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> intval и int у
> $xml->operation->amount; не помог.

И не должен был помочь, так как int - целочисленный.
Вам нужен floatval

Comment: @knes, но не всегда же будут у меня числа с плавающей запятой. Что будет с floatval, если число будет целым?

Comment: Странно, но floatval и с целыми числами работает :o